# Skuber delete items in a specific namespace

Tags: scala, kubernetes

I am using skuber 2.4.0.

Is there a way to use the skuber client.delete an object in a specific namespace?

I understand that when I create a client I can specify a namespace.
But for example when creating a job you can specify any namespace in the metadata.

Seems weird to need to create a new client just for deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you open an issue in the github repo for further help.
https://github.com/hagay3/skuber/issues

**EDIT:**

Namespaces API is now available in version 2.7.6

It's possible to provide namespace in every client endpoint.
https://github.com/hagay3/skuber/releases/tag/v2.7.6

**OLD ANSWER:**

Regarding your question, you can use the following method:

`def usingNamespace(newNamespace: String): KubernetesClient`

https://github.com/hagay3/skuber/blob/master/client/src/main/scala/skuber/api/client/KubernetesClient.scala#L366

example:
https://github.com/hagay3/skuber/blob/master/client/src/it/scala/skuber/NamespaceSpec.scala#L53

Comment: This will still create a new client but I guess it's the best option atm. Thanks!

Comment: @harel I released namespaced API :) - see my edit